# ASM chart query

Tags: vhdl

I have a very general question when constructing an ASM chart. I'm reading a book and I am working on a project where I need to construct an ASM chart for a lock system. Essentially the question boils down to the following, can I put two conditions inside a decision box of the ASM chart?
something like that: **if(enter='1' and reset = '0')**

Thank you